# "Плавающий" футер

Tags: html, css, style, position

Добрый день!

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: имеется html структура:

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
      #container{
        min-height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
      }
        .item1{
          position: relative;
          width: 50%;
          height: 50px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          background-color: green;
        }
          .item2{
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            height: 1000px;
            background-color: blue;
          }
      #footer{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
      }
```

```html
<body>

<div id='container'>
  <div class='item1'>
    <div class='item2'></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='footer'><div>

</body>
```

Все работает отлично, но стоит элементу .item2 принять большую height, экран соответственно удлиняется, и футер оказывается "парящим" в воздухе[image: общий вид]

Можно ли как-то избежать этого, не убирая абсолютное позиционирование внутреннего элемента?

Comment: Задача в том, чтобы прибить футер к низу или прибить к низу + чтобы он был позиционирован абсолютно?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, видимо не совсем понятно сформулировал, обновил вопрос

Comment: у вас сайт как я понял имеет структуру на основе php, там футер во всяком случае будет плавать, в интернете есть описание аж 5 способов как решить эту задачу. Как вариант можно засунуть его в #container со следующими значениями position: relative; top: 100%;

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='container'></div>
  <div id='footer'>
    <div>
</body>
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. При таком подходе получается то же самое

Answer (score 0):

Рабатает с position:absolute;

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
      .item1{
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: green;
    }
      .item2{
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
     
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='container'>
   <div class='item1'>
     <div class='item2'></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id='footer'>
    <div>
</body>
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. При вашем подходе получается то же самое

Comment: можете обьяснить что не получается?

Comment: Получается то же самое, что и в моем случае, элемент item2 выходит за границы футера вниз

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, пригодится решение - отступ в body снизу равный высоте подвала, а подвал позиционировать фиксированно.

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom:50px
      padding: 0;
    }
      #container{
        min-height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
      }
        .item1{
          position: relative;
          width: 50%;
          height: 50px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          background-color: green;
        }
          .item2{
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            height: 1000px;
            background-color: blue;
          }
      #footer{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
      }
```

```html
<body>

<div id='container'>
  <div class='item1'>
    <div class='item2'></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='footer'><div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Плавающий футер, если я правильно понял, это фиксированный снизу футер + марджин для элемента `.item2`, чтобы его не скрывал футер.

```css
body, html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
      #container{
        min-height: 100%;
      }
        .item1{
          position: relative;
          width: 50%;
          height: 50px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          background-color: green;
        }
          .item2{
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            height: 1000px;
            background-color: blue;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
          }
      #footer{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: .3;
      }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='item1'>
    <div class='item2'></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='footer'><div>
```

Comment: В вашем примере футер двигается вместе со скроллом, я хотел, чтобы он находился снизу страницы. Видимо, так невозможно..

Comment: вам необходимо, чтобы при маленьком количестве контента футер был прижат к низу страницы, а при большом количестве — вел себя как обычный блок?

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы футер всегда был прижат к низу страницы, даже если в контейнере есть абсолютно позиционированный блок с высотой, превышающей статичную высоту страницы